# Using Modulo instead of two loops

Tags: c#, for-loop, modulo

I'm new at programming in general and learning C# right now.

I just wrote a little programm where I have to step through an int[] in a specific pattern. The pattern is as follows:

- Start at the last entry of the array (int i)
- form the sum of i and (if avaible) the three entrys above (e.g. i += i-1 ... i += i-3)
- Change i to i -= 4 (if avaible)
- Repeat from step 2 until i = 0;

Therefore i wrote the following loop:

```
        for (int i = intArray.Length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 4)
        {
            for (int a = 1; a <= 3; a++)
            {
                if (i - a >= 0)
                {
                    intArray[i] += intArray[i - a];
                    intArray[i - a] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
```

Now my new assignment is to change my code to only use **1 loop** with the help of modulo-operations. I do understand what modulo does, but i can't figure out how to use it to get rid of the second loop.

Maybe somebody explain it to me? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Modulo is also called the [remainder operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator-). For example: 6 % 2 returns 0, but 6 % 4 returns the remainder 2 (4 goes into 6 one time, and then 2 is left over).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Sure, you can ask random strangers on the internet for advice, but since this is an assignment, the most appropriate person to help you would be your teacher. It's (literally) their job to do that! And they know you, your previous knowledge and the didactic goal of the exercise much better than we do.

Comment: does your code really work as expected up to now?

Comment: Yes it does 100% bulletproof.

Comment: @Heinzi
Please don't focus to much on the word "assignment". It's not like I am learning it at school or something. I just started learning C# as a free time activity.

Comment: Thanks also to you @DiplomacyNotWar but as I said, I don't have any trouble understanding the concept of modulo. My problem is, that i don't know how to use the remainders to controll my loop

Comment: Presumably `i % 4` so that you can iterate through the array without the `-4` step. `intArray[i]` would become `intArray[i % 4]` I think, and then you wouldn't need the inner loop since you could do it in one pass. I've not tested this though, but it looks about right.

Comment: I think i got it now, thanks

Comment: If you struggle, take a look at [this sample](https://rextester.com/RCABS97215).

Comment: Thank you very much. I did'nt quiet figure out how to make it work but your solution does the job just fine. Well I guess now I just have to completely understand it.
EDIT: No i was wrong, there is still some error when further testing my code... Thanks anyway for the very helpfull sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While iterating over the array, the idea would be to use the modulo 4 operation to calculate the next index to which you will add the current value.

This should work with any array lengths:

```cs
        for (int i = 0; i < intArray.Length; i++){
            // we check how far away we are from next index which stores the sum
            var offset = (intArray.Length - 1 - i) % 4;
            if (offset == 0) continue;
            intArray[i+offset] += intArray[i];
            intArray[i] = 0;
        }
```

Comment: This is it. I just changed it up a bit to start from the bottom of the array by doing 'for (int i = userInput.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)'
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

iterating the array reversely makes it a bit more complicated, but what you wanted to get rid of inner loop with modulo is probably this:

```
        var intArray = Enumerable.Range(1, 15).ToArray();

        for (int i = 1; i < intArray.Length - 1;  i ++)
        {
            intArray[i - (i % 4)] += intArray[i];
            intArray[i] = 0;
        }
```

Comment: this does not produce the same result as the nested loop from the question

Comment: true, I did not solve his home work alike task 100% but answered the main question, how to get rid of the 2nd loop with modulo's help. Now it should be obvious how to use it.